# I don't know where to start with this inequality problem, right

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

Let $1 < p < +\infty$, $M \ge \max\{p-1,1/(p-1)\}$. prove:

> For any $x, y \ge 0$, following inequality holds
>   $$p(Mx - y)(x+y)^{p-1} \le (M+1)^{p-1}M^{1-p}(M^p x^p - y^p).$$

Comment: this is the first time for me to ask a question. I'm not very good at operation,thank you very much .

Comment: Please don't repost [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3651642) with no efforts shown at all. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).